# How to recreate T-SNE dimensions deterministically?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, tsne

So I have a set of 3000 features from which I would like to generate clusters. I passed my features through the T-SNE algorithm to reduce dimensionality to 2 features, and clusters are really visible in this reduced space. How would I go about figuring out a deterministic way to create this same T-SNE output to use for clustering?

Comment: Re-use the random number seed; e.g., using `random_state` in [sklearn.manifold.TSNE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html). Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use tSNE visualizations for clustering. The results are misleading.

See this great answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/264647/7828

Apart from that, you just need to fix the initial positions. For examples by fixing the random generator seed. But the fact thar it does *not* work every time should already warn you that it is not too reliable...